# Django South - table already exists

Tags: django, django-south

I am trying to get started with South.  I had an existing database and I added South (`syncdb`, `schemamigration --initial`).

Then, I updated `models.py` to add a field and ran `./manage.py schemamigration myapp --auto`. It seemed to find the field and said I could apply this with `./manage.py migrate myapp`. But, doing that gave the error:

```
django.db.utils.DatabaseError: table "myapp_tablename" already exists
```

`tablename` is the first table listed in `models.py`.

I am running Django 1.2, South 0.7

Answer (score 313, accepted):

since you already have the tables created in the database, you just need to run the initial migration as fake

```
./manage.py migrate myapp --fake
```

make sure that the schema of models is same as schema of tables in database.

Comment: Got it, thanks. It's actually migrate and not schemamigration, but your answer got me in the right direction.

Comment: my mistake just copied the command from OP, correct command
./manage.py migrate myapp --fake

Comment: This solution didn't solve the problem in my case. I didn't modify the database and crashed some views because the field wasn't created on the table. I had to comment the new property, migrate with fake again to reestablish everything, and the second time I tried it did worked which I still don't understand... :)

Comment: @Ashok maybe you should also specify we have to redo a `schemamigration` before the `migrate` in case we already did modifications before the last `schemamigration`.

Comment: @Dave, :))))))) the most funny comment i ever saw!! i also love it! great, dude! :D

Comment: This did not help me. I already had a table in my database, and after faking the migration, there was no way to add the other tables that were faked. I had to drop all tables and start fresh.

Comment: Another option is to skip `./manage.py schemamigration myapp --inital` and use [`./manage.py convert_to_south myapp`](http://south.readthedocs.org/en/latest/convertinganapp.html#converting-an-app) instead. The docs also say though that if propagating changes via VCS then use `--fake` on the other clones after using `convert_to_south` and pushing/pulling changes.

Answer (score 41):

> Although the table "myapp_tablename" already exists error stop raising
>   after I did ./manage.py migrate myapp --fake, the DatabaseError shows
>   no such column: myapp_mymodel.added_field.

Got exactly the same problem!

1.Firstly **check the migration number** which is causing this. Lets assume it is: 0010.

2.You need to:

```
./manage.py schemamigration myapp --add-field MyModel.added_field
./manage.py migrate myapp
```

if there is more than one field missing you have to repeat it for each field.

3.Now you land with a bunch of new migrations so **remove their files** from myapp/migrations (0011 and further if you needed to add multiple fields).

4.Run this:

```
./manage.py migrate myapp 0010
```

Now try ./manage.py migrate myapp

If it doesn't fail you're ready. Just doublecheck if any field's aren't missing.

EDIT:

This problem can also occur when you have a production database for which you install South and the first, initial migration created in other enviorment duplicates what you already have in your db. The solution is much easier here:

1. Fake the first migration:

   ./manage migrate myapp 0001 --fake
2. Roll with the rest of migrations:

   ./manage migrate myapp

Answer (score 11):

When I ran into this error, it had a different cause.

In my case South had somehow left in my DB a temporary empty table, which is used in [_remake_table()](https://github.com/dmishe/django-south/blob/master/south/db/sqlite3.py). Probably I had aborted a migration in a way I shouldn't have. In any case, each subsequent new migration, when it called _remake_table(), was throwing the error `sqlite3.pypysqlite2.dbapi2.OperationalError: table "_south_new_myapp_mymodel" already exists`, because it *did* already exist and wasn't supposed to be there.

The _south_new bit looked odd to me, so I browsed my DB, saw the table `_south_new_myapp_mymodel`, scratched my head, looked at [South's source](https://github.com/dmishe/django-south/blob/master/south/db/sqlite3.py), decided it was junk, dropped the table, and all was well.

Comment: This is what I saw, and had I found this, would have saved me half hour of brainache. Pretty unpleasant - but these are temporary migration tables, and are left around during a failed migration, probably for the purposes of inspection. Mine occurred due to some db integrity issue during the migration attempt.

Comment: This needs to be higher up! If you are using a db w/o schema transactions this can happen pretty easily

Answer (score 2):

If you have problems with your models not matching your database, like @pielgrzym, and you want to automatically migrate the database to match the latest models.py file (and erase any data that won't be recreated by fixtures during `migrate`):

```
manage.py schemamigration myapp --initial
manage.py migrate myapp --fake
manage.py migrate myapp zero
manage.py migrate myapp
```

This will only delete and recreate database tables that exist in your latest `models.py` file, so you may have garbage tables in your database from previous `syncdb`s or `migrate`s. To get rid of those, precede all these migrations with:

```
manage.py sqlclear myapp | manage.py sqlshell
```

And if that still leaves some CRUFT lying around in your database then you'll have to do an `inspectdb` and create the `models.py` file from that (for the tables and app that you want to clear) before doing the `sqlclear` and then restore your original models.py before creating the `--initial` migration and migrating to it.  All this to avoid messing around with the particular flavor of SQL that your database needs.

Answer (score 1):

`Perform these steps in order may help you`:

1) python manage.py schemamigration apps.appname --initial

Above step creates migration folder as default.

2) python manage.py migrate apps.appname --fake

generates a fake migration.

3) python manage.py schemamigration apps.appname --auto

Then you can add fields as you wish and perform the above command.

4) python manage.py migrate apps.appname

Answer (score 1):

If you have an existing database and app you can use the south conversion command

```
./manage.py convert_to_south myapp
```

This has to be applied **before** you do any changes to what is already in the database.

The convert_to_south command only works entirely on the first machine you run it on. Once you’ve committed the initial migrations it made into your VCS, you’ll have to run `./manage.py migrate myapp 0001 --fake` on every machine that has a copy of the codebase (make sure they were up-to-date with models and schema first).
ref: http://south.readthedocs.org/en/latest/convertinganapp.html

Answer (score 0):

As temporary solution, you can comment the Table creation in the migration script.

```
class Migration(migrations.Migration):

    dependencies = [
        (...)
    ]

    operations = [
        #migrations.CreateModel(
        #    name='TABLE',
        #    fields=[
        #            ....
        #            ....
        #    ],
        #),
        ....
        ....
```

---

Or

If the existing table contains no rows (empty), then consider deleting the table like below. **(This fix is recommended only if the table contains no rows)**. Also make sure this operation before the createModel operation.

```
class Migration(migrations.Migration):

    dependencies = [
        (...),
    ]

    operations = [
        migrations.RunSQL("DROP TABLE myapp_tablename;")
    ]
```

Answer (score 0):

One more solution(maybe a temporary solution).

```
$ python manage.py sqlmigrate APP_NAME MIGRATION_NAME
```

eg.,.

```
$ python manage.py sqlmigrate users 0029_auto_20170310_1117
```

This will list all the migrations in raw sql queries. You can pick the queries which you want to run avoiding the part which creates the existing table