# Django South "myapp.foo" already exists" error with initial migration

Tags: django, django-models, django-south

I have an already existing app **with alot of database entries**.

```
class Foo(models.Model):
    value = models.TextField(u"Value")
```

For this I do this:

```
python manage.py schemamigration myapp --initial
python  manage.py migrate myapp
```

I change the model to such:

```
class Foo(models.Model):
    value = models.TextField(u"Value")
    live = models.BooleanField(u"Live", default=False)
    creation_time = models.DateTimeField("Creation Time", auto_now_add=True, null=True, blank=True)
```

and migrate:

```
python manage.py schemamigration myapp --auto
python  manage.py migrate myapp
```

I get `django.db.utils.DatabaseError: relation "myapp.foo" already exists` error.

I have already checked [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3090648/django-south-table-already-exists) question but --fake doesn't seem to be supported via South anymore.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your models look invalid to me, though I'd be surprised if that's what's actually causing the problem.

It looks like your first argument is intended to be the [`verbose_name`](http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/fields/#verbose-name) attribute, your model should probably look like this:

```
class Foo(models.Model):
    value = models.TextField(verbose_name = u"Value")
    live = models.BooleanField(verbose_name = u"Live", default=False)
    creation_time = models.DateTimeField(verbose_name = u"Creation Time", auto_now_add=True, null=True, blank=True)
```

(you also forgot the `u` before the `verbose_name` for `creation_time`).

Meanwhile, `--fake` is definitely still supported (see the [docs](http://south.aeracode.org/docs/convertinganapp.html)), what error are you getting when you try and run it?

Comment: What Dominic said. I have successfully used `--fake` with the latest version of South. Something else is going wrong.

Comment: I tried to use --fake with schemamigration command, not migrate. Thanks alot Dominic!