# No Such Column Error in Django App After South Migration

Tags: django, django-south

I've run into the same issue presented by the commenter here: [Django South - table already exists](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3090648/django-south-table-already-exists/3130029#3130029)

There was no follow-up, so I thought I'd post a new question. I have a Django app whose migrations I manage with South. I added a field to my model then ran

```
./manage schemamigration my_app --auto
```

which ran as expected. Running

```
./manage migrate my_app
```

however, resulted in an error indicating that the table associated with the model I changed already exists. This led me to the above linked question, so running

```
./manage migrate my_app --fake
```

resolved the table error, but now I'm getting a Django error that the column associated with the new field does not exist.

```
./manage sqlall my_app
```

shows the schema to be as expected.

Any thoughts on how to remedy this are appreciated!

Answer (score 34, accepted):

Probably easiest way for you will be to start migrations from scratch.

Delete all `migrations/*` files for the app which you try to fix. Restore your `models.py` to the state which is at the moment on the database (by the help of version control tools, or just comment out the new fields). Then initialize migrations:

```
manage.py migrate my_app --delete-ghost-migrations
manage.py schemamigration my_app --init
manage.py migrate my_app --fake
```

This will create a record in migrations of what current database structure looks like.

Now add your changes to `models.py` and south will now what has changed:

```
manage.py schemamigration my_app --auto
manage.py migrate my_app
```

Comment: Make also sure to delete all database entries about schema migrations south has made before as well (if you screwed up). @drew: your main mistake was that you should have made the initali migration and run `./manage migrate my_app --fake` BEFORE adding the new field to the model!

Comment: @lazerscience `manage.py migrate my_app --delete-ghost-migrations` does the thing.

Comment: Thank you so much. South can get complicated at times.

Answer (score 6):

Something else to keep an eye out for: you will often get this error (`DatabaseError: no such column: appname_model.fieldname`) if you are using a `default` value in a `ForeignKey` relation, and you add a field to that FK model.

Something like (in your `models.py`):

```
class MyAppModel(models.Model):
    my_foreign_key = models.ForeignKey(FkModel,
                                       default=lambda: FkModel.objects.get(id=1),
                                       null=True)
```

Then in a new migration, you add a new field to your FkModel:

```
class FkModel(models.Model):
    new_field = models.IntegerField('New Field Name', blank=True, null=True)
```

You will get an error when running a South `schemamigration`:

`DatabaseError: no such column: myappmodel_fkmodel.new_field`

You can solve this by making sure your initial South migration includes this default value `lambda` function, but then remove the default value in the next migration.

This has bitten me in the past. Hopefully it will help someone in the future.

Answer (score 0):

for beginners or learners if ur stucked here and dont mind DATA LOSE(all) then just delete db.sqlit3 file and re run server it should reset the sqlite