# No Such Column After South Migration

Tags: python, django, migration, django-south

I had the same issue as the user in this question but the [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4119150/2270375) unfortunately did not resolve anything. A few comments about what happened when I followed the given directions:

When I tried the `--delete-ghost-migrations` command I got an error

`The app 'tixeng' does not appear to use migrations.`

I moved forward with the directions and initialized migrations for the app. Then I tried the `--delete-ghost-migrations` again

```
/Users/AaronPardes/Dropbox/Python/home_repos/squidtix/squidtix/virtualenvironments/squidtixENV/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/utils/hashcompat.py:9: DeprecationWarning:  django.utils.hashcompat is deprecated; use hashlib instead
  DeprecationWarning)

Running migrations for tixeng:
- Nothing to migrate.
- Loading initial data for tixeng.
Installed 0 object(s) from 0 fixture(s)
```

I then made the changes to my model, and tried to create a new migration for the changes.

```
^C(squidtixENV)Aarons-MacBook-Pro:squidtix AaronPardes$ ./manage.py schemamigration tixeng --auto
+ Added field for_sale on tixeng.SquidTic
Created 0002_auto__add_field_squidtic_for_sale.py. You can now apply this migration with: ./manage.py migrate tixeng
```

And applying the migration.

```
/Users/AaronPardes/Dropbox/Python/home_repos/squidtix/squidtix/virtualenvironments/squidtixENV   /lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/utils/hashcompat.py:9: DeprecationWarning:   django.utils.hashcompat is deprecated; use hashlib instead
  DeprecationWarning)

Running migrations for tixeng:
- Migrating forwards to 0002_auto__add_field_squidtic_for_sale.
> tixeng:0002_auto__add_field_squidtic_for_sale
FATAL ERROR - The following SQL query failed: CREATE TABLE "_south_new_tixeng_squidtic"      ("date_listed" datetime NOT NULL, "event_id" integer NOT NULL, "price" integer NOT NULL, "for_sale" bool NOT NULL DEFAULT 1, "id" integer PRIMARY KEY, "owner_id" integer)
The error was: table "_south_new_tixeng_squidtic" already exists
 ! Error found during real run of migration! Aborting.

 ! Since you have a database that does not support running
 ! schema-altering statements in transactions, we have had 
 ! to leave it in an interim state between migrations.

! You *might* be able to recover with:
 ! The South developers regret this has happened, and would
 ! like to gently persuade you to consider a slightly
 ! easier-to-deal-with DBMS (one that supports DDL transactions)
 ! NOTE: The error which caused the migration to fail is further up.
Error in migration: tixeng:0002_auto__add_field_squidtic_for_sale
DatabaseError: table "_south_new_tixeng_squidtic" already exists
```

Relevant Information:

field being added: `models.BooleanField(default = True)`

The migration that is created:

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
import datetime
from south.db import db
from south.v2 import SchemaMigration
from django.db import models


class Migration(SchemaMigration):

    def forwards(self, orm):
        # Adding field 'SquidTic.for_sale'
        db.add_column(u'tixeng_squidtic', 'for_sale',
                  self.gf('django.db.models.fields.BooleanField')(default=True),
                  keep_default=False)


    def backwards(self, orm):
        # Deleting field 'SquidTic.for_sale'
        db.delete_column(u'tixeng_squidtic', 'for_sale')


    models = {
        u'accounts.myprofile': {
            'Meta': {'object_name': 'MyProfile'},
            'favourite_snack': ('django.db.models.fields.CharField', [], {'max_length': '5'}),
            u'id': ('django.db.models.fields.AutoField', [], {'primary_key': 'True'}),
            'mugshot': ('django.db.models.fields.files.ImageField', [], {'max_length': '100',  'blank': 'True'}),
            'privacy': ('django.db.models.fields.CharField', [], {'default': "'registered'", 'max_length': '15'}),
            'user': ('django.db.models.fields.related.OneToOneField', [], {'related_name': "'my_profile'", 'unique': 'True', 'to': u"orm['auth.User']"})
        },
        u'auth.group': {
            'Meta': {'object_name': 'Group'},
            u'id': ('django.db.models.fields.AutoField', [], {'primary_key': 'True'}),
            'name': ('django.db.models.fields.CharField', [], {'unique': 'True', 'max_length': '80'}),
            'permissions': ('django.db.models.fields.related.ManyToManyField', [], {'to': u"orm['auth.Permission']", 'symmetrical': 'False', 'blank': 'True'})
        },
        u'auth.permission': {
            'Meta': {'ordering': "(u'content_type__app_label', u'content_type__model', u'codename')", 'unique_together': "((u'content_type', u'codename'),)", 'object_name': 'Permission'},
            'codename': ('django.db.models.fields.CharField', [], {'max_length': '100'}),
            'content_type': ('django.db.models.fields.related.ForeignKey', [], {'to': u"orm['contenttypes.ContentType']"}),
            u'id': ('django.db.models.fields.AutoField', [], {'primary_key': 'True'}),
            'name': ('django.db.models.fields.CharField', [], {'max_length': '50'})
        },
        u'auth.user': {
            'Meta': {'object_name': 'User'},
            'date_joined': ('django.db.models.fields.DateTimeField', [], {'default':   'datetime.datetime.now'}),
            'email': ('django.db.models.fields.EmailField', [], {'max_length': '75', 'blank': 'True'}),
            'first_name': ('django.db.models.fields.CharField', [], {'max_length': '30', 'blank': 'True'}),
            'groups': ('django.db.models.fields.related.ManyToManyField', [], {'to': u"orm['auth.Group']", 'symmetrical': 'False', 'blank': 'True'}),
            u'id': ('django.db.models.fields.AutoField', [], {'primary_key': 'True'}),
            'is_active': ('django.db.models.fields.BooleanField', [], {'default': 'True'}),
            'is_staff': ('django.db.models.fields.BooleanField', [], {'default': 'False'}),
            'is_superuser': ('django.db.models.fields.BooleanField', [], {'default': 'False'}),
            'last_login': ('django.db.models.fields.DateTimeField', [], {'default': 'datetime.datetime.now'}),
            'last_name': ('django.db.models.fields.CharField', [], {'max_length': '30', 'blank': 'True'}),
            'password': ('django.db.models.fields.CharField', [], {'max_length': '128'}),
            'user_permissions': ('django.db.models.fields.related.ManyToManyField', [], {'to': u"orm['auth.Permission']", 'symmetrical': 'False', 'blank': 'True'}),
            'username': ('django.db.models.fields.CharField', [], {'unique': 'True', 'max_length': '30'})
        },
        u'contenttypes.contenttype': {
            'Meta': {'ordering': "('name',)", 'unique_together': "(('app_label', 'model'),)", 'object_name': 'ContentType', 'db_table': "'django_content_type'"},
            'app_label': ('django.db.models.fields.CharField', [], {'max_length': '100'}),
            u'id': ('django.db.models.fields.AutoField', [], {'primary_key': 'True'}),
            'model': ('django.db.models.fields.CharField', [], {'max_length': '100'}),
            'name': ('django.db.models.fields.CharField', [], {'max_length': '100'})
        },
        u'tixeng.squidartist': {
            'Meta': {'object_name': 'SquidArtist'},
            'artist_name': ('django.db.models.fields.CharField', [], {'max_length': '20'}),
            u'id': ('django.db.models.fields.AutoField', [], {'primary_key': 'True'}),
            'name': ('django.db.models.fields.CharField', [], {'max_length': '20'})
        },
        u'tixeng.squidevent': {
            'Meta': {'object_name': 'SquidEvent'},
            'artist': ('django.db.models.fields.related.ManyToManyField', [], {'to': u"orm['tixeng.SquidArtist']", 'symmetrical': 'False'}),
            'event_date': ('django.db.models.fields.DateTimeField', [], {}),
            u'id': ('django.db.models.fields.AutoField', [], {'primary_key': 'True'}),
            'name': ('django.db.models.fields.CharField', [], {'max_length': '20'}),
            'venue': ('django.db.models.fields.related.ForeignKey', [], {'to': u"orm['tixeng.SquidVenue']"})
        },
        u'tixeng.squidtic': {
            'Meta': {'object_name': 'SquidTic'},
            'date_listed': ('django.db.models.fields.DateTimeField', [], {}),
            'event': ('django.db.models.fields.related.ForeignKey', [], {'to': u"orm['tixeng.SquidEvent']"}),
            'for_sale': ('django.db.models.fields.BooleanField', [], {'default': 'True'}),
            u'id': ('django.db.models.fields.AutoField', [], {'primary_key': 'True'}),
            'owner': ('django.db.models.fields.related.ForeignKey', [], {'to': u"orm['accounts.MyProfile']"}),
            'price': ('django.db.models.fields.IntegerField', [], {'default': '0.0'})
        },
        u'tixeng.squidvenue': {
            'Meta': {'object_name': 'SquidVenue'},
            u'id': ('django.db.models.fields.AutoField', [], {'primary_key': 'True'}),
            'name': ('django.db.models.fields.CharField', [], {'max_length': '20'}),
            'street_address': ('django.db.models.fields.CharField', [], {'max_length': '20'})
        }
    }

    complete_apps = ['tixeng']
```

Comment: Did you fake migrations ?

Comment: I did after I deleted the ghost migrations

Comment: I really cannot figure out what the issue is, I've searched all over and while I find solutions, none actually solve the problem for me.

Comment: You should paste more code and outputs of stuff you tried. Obviously you've got some migrations applied wrong but I can't "guess" which one exactly given the information in your question.

Comment: Can you be more specific as to what I should post? I put up everything that I thought was relevant. Thanks.

Comment: For example, you say "I tried --delete-ghost-migrations and I'm getting No such column". Here, it would be good that you paste the whole command line including all options as well as all the output.

Comment: Is it possible that you ran syncdb to create a model table for a model of an app managed by south ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So in the end I decided to start from scratch with a new database. Once I set everything up again properly it was fully functional. Still not sure what my issue was but this resolved it.

Answer (score 0):

I'll take an educated guess: you have created a new model in an app managed by south, but you used syncdb to create its table. Now you can add a field to this table and this is how to fix it.

1. **Before you add the field, create a schema migration**. It should create the migration with the new model table.
2. **Apply this new migration with `--fake`**, it will not create the table but it will tell south that this migration is done.
3. **Now add the field, create a schema migration**. It should create the migration that adds the field to the table.
4. **Apply this new migration** normally, no `--fake`.

Comment: `DatabaseError: table "_south_new_tixeng_squidtic" already exists` is what I get when I try and apply your step 4. Everything worked without issue up until that point.

Comment: That's funny, could you paste the migration script created in step 3 ?

Comment: Updated with the migration