# django - "manage.py test" fails "table already exists"

Tags: python, django

I'm new to the django world. Running some tutorial apps, and when running python manage.py test i'm getting a failure saying that the table already exists. I'm not sure what is going on. I am also running south, and I got no errors when migrating the schema.

Any insight is greatly appreciated.

TIA
Joey

Comment: Possibly related:  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3090648/django-south-table-already-exists

Comment: YES! That was it, I made some mistakes and got migration out of sync with the db. clean installs fixed it right up.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

It might be an error in one of your south migrations. You don't see the problem on the real db because the migration has been executed (with the--fake option maybe)

You can try to recreate the db from scracth and see if it works.

You can also disable South for unit-tests by adding `SOUTH_TESTS_MIGRATE = False` in your settings.py. With this option a regular syncdb will be done to create the test database. It will also speed the testing process.

I hope it helps

Comment: if i have to draw db from scratch then what's the benefit of South?

Comment: @Ahsan the DB is created from scratch only for tests and it happens this way whether or not you use South.

Comment: ++ for SOUTH_TESTS_MIGRATE = False

Answer (score 3):

This also happened to me with a legacy code but for another reason.

I had two models with db_table referencing the same db table.
I know that is stupid, but it's not my fault )

And I never found anything on the internet that could help me.
I was saved by verbosity set to 3 (manage.py test -v 3)
Hope this helps anyone.

```
class Bla1(Model):
    some_column = ...
    class Meta:
        db_table = 'some_table'

class Bla2(Model):
    some_column = ...
    class Meta:
        db_table = 'some_table'
```

Comment: helped, fixed tracking which models are set to managed in a custom [TestRunner](https://dev.to/vergeev/testing-against-unmanaged-models-in-django) and keep `managed=False` in any model refrencing an already referenced table.

Answer (score 0):

and if you are testing with nose:

DST_RUN_SOUTH_MIGRATIONS = False

Answer (score 0):

This happens also with Nose when
`--cover-package=userdata,incorrectname`
One of package's name is incorrect

Answer (score 0):

You have to similar models, check it