# to add new classes in models.py without modifying the data associated with existing model classes in django

Tags: python, mysql, django, django-models

I want to add some set of classes to models.py file in the django app which already has some classes created in that synchronized and contain data in each one of them in the database (created in mysql).

when I add new classes and type command

```
python manage.py makemigrations app-label//(using django 1.8 version)
```

it shows the

```
creating table names ...
```

but I when I run :

```
   python manage.py migrate
```

it shows ...

```
  table "access_log" already exists
```

I have tried many of the stack overflow links but nothing helped me. Like few of them are :

[link 1 -stack-overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25924858/django-1-7-migtate-gets-error-table-already-exists)

[link 2 -stack-overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3090648/django-south-table-already-exists)

[link 3 -stack-overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29888046/django-1-8-create-initial-migrations-for-existing-schema)

Also my exiting tables with data in database have attribute managed = false. Will that affect ?

Why is this happening?

Please help, I am not much well-versed with django.

Comment: Try look into your SQL db - your tables should be named like `appname_modelname` - do you already have an app named `access` with a model `log` in your db, e.g. `access_log`? If so, do you recognize the data?

Comment: @henrikstroem : my app name is fcui, the table access_log is the model previously created in the models.py for which managed = false. it has data too. My issue is that I am not able to add new classes to models.py

Comment: I must be missing something, sorry. If you have removed an unmanaged table, Django will not remove the database table for you, you must do that manually if you are creating a table with the same name.

Comment: @henrikstroem : i am not creating the table with same name, it is like i had say class abcd was already present in the models.py and had the data in the database (which is access_log in my case), in that class, sub-class meta has managed = false. Now, i am adding a new class with name

Comment: account_users to models .py . After adding, i ran `python manage.py makemigrations app_name` and then `python manage.py migrate`

Comment: Have you looked at this: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/ref/django-admin/#showmigrations-app-label-app-label - maybe it will shine some light on the problem.